# How to iterate through dictionary where keys are pairs?

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I am creating a dictionary representation of a chessboard, where the keys are coordinate pairs representing a position and the values are a string representing the type of piece.  For example:

```
playerPieces = { (0,0):'R', (1,0):'S', (2,0):'B', (3,0):'Q' ... }
```

There is one such dictionary for both players.  My problem comes in trying to iterate over all of a player's pieces.  I have tried three different approaches, none of which seems to work.

1. If I try to unpack the dictionary into key, value pairs like so:

   `for position, piece in playerPieces:`

instead, `position` and `piece` respectively unpack the first and second elements of the key pair (so for the first iteration through `playerPieces` I would get `position == 0` and `piece == 0`.  Not very helpful.

2. If instead I try the following:

   `for (col, row), piece in playerPieces:`

I get the error `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`, which I currently do not understand.

3. Finally, if I get rid of the parentheses around the column, row pair like so:

   `for col, row, piece in playerPieces:`

I of course get the error `ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack`.

So then, what other option is there?  Can this be done?  The second option seemed like the most likely one to me so I imagine that understanding the TypeError holds the key to figuring out what's going on, but I'm kind of at a loss.

Comment: `for (col, row), piece in playerPieces.items()`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to iterate over a dictionary's items:

```
for (col, row), piece in d.items():
    print(col, row, piece)
```

iterating over a `dict` will merely iterate over its keys.

Comment: D'OH!  Now I feel a fool.  I'll accept this answer once enough time has passed that I'm allowed to.  >_0

Answer (score 3):

By default, Python iterates over the key values in a dictionary, which is the reason why `for position, piece in playerPieces:` simply pulled off the two values from each key and the main source of your confusion.

With that in mind, simply iterate over the keys and then access each element. Using an example like the one below will accomplish what you're trying to do.

```
for position in playerPieces:
    piece = playerPieces[position]
```

Answer (score -1):

Use iteritems:

```
playerPieces = { (0,0):'R', (1,0):'S', (2,0):'B', (3,0):'Q'}

for position, piece in playerPieces.iteritems():
    print position, piece
```

Output:

```
(3, 0) Q
(2, 0) B
(1, 0) S
(0, 0) R
```